# Prove value absolute inequality

Tags: inequality

I need to prove this:

$$|a-1| + |a-2| + |a-3| \geq 2$$

I tryed to play with the absolute values, but I'm stuck.

Any hints?

Comment: Have you tried to sketch a graph of the LHS with respect fo $a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $|a| + |b| \geq |a - b|$

---

Therefore,
 $$|a - 1| + |a - 2| + |a - 3| \geq |a - 2| + |(a - 1) - (a - 3)| = |a - 2| + 2 \geq 2$$

Comment: Got it, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Call b = a - 2, what you need to prove is that 2 is the smallest value of the function $f(b) = |b-1| + |b| + |b + 1|$. Note that $f(b)$ is the sum of distances from a point $b$ to $0$, $-1$ and $+1$.

1. Take $b$ the right of $1$, $b \ge 1$, in this case $f(b) = (1 + b) + (b) + (b - 1) = 3 b \ge 3 $. Same applies for $b \le -1$
2. Now take $b$ between $0$ and $1$, $0 \le b \le 1$, for this situation the distances are $f(b) = (1 + b) + (b) + (1 - b) = 2+ b$, which is minimum when $b = 0$ and in this case $f(b = 0) = 2$. Same argument goes for when $-1 \le b \le 0$

That is, the sum of the distances is minimum when you are in the middle of the three points!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\geq2$

Hence, $|a-1|+|a-2|+|a-3|=a-1+|a-2|+|3-a|\geq1+|a-2+3-a|=2$.

Let $a\leq2$.

Hence, $|a-1|+|a-2|+|a-3|=|a-3|+|2-a|+|a-1|\geq1+|2-a+a-1|=2$.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

By the triangle inequality: $$\require{cancel} |a-1|+|3-a| \ge |\cancel{a}-1+3-\cancel{a}|=2$$

Geometrically, the sum of distances to points $1,3$ which are $3-1=2$ apart must be at least $2$. The middle term $|a-2|$ is not even needed for the inequality to hold.